# How To Select Where Foreign Key Doesn't Exist in Other Column and Compare Dates From Tables That Aren't Directly Linked

Tags: mysql, sql

EER-DIAGRAM DATABASE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v87y.jpg

So how this works is that I have a php application where a user can give his available dates (see table: availableDates) for a certain course. Based on that preference the system will give him course executions information (see table: courseExecutions) that meet his criteria for which he can then sign up to, meaning that the SQL-query must have the following requirements:

- SELECT courseExecution.courseExecutionID, courseExecution.beginDate, courseExecution.endDate, course.title, course.price, co.city **WHERE**:
- A person has not yet signed up for this execution, this gets checked in the participant table, if courseExecutionID is not linked to a participantID in the participant table then he has not signed up yet.
- The CourseExecution must not be done, pretty simple just check whether the done column is 0.
- availableDates.beginDate is smaller (<) than courseExecution.beginDate
- availableDates.endDate is greater (>) than courseExecution.endDAte

I have written a lot of queries but none of them have managed to cover the use case. A (non-working) example would be:

```
SELECT c.courseExecutionID, c.beginDate, c.endDate, co.title, co.price, co.title
FROM courseExecution c
JOIN course co
ON c.courseID = co.courseID
JOIN availableDates a
ON co.courseID = a.courseID
JOIN person p 
ON a.personID = p.personID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT personID FROM participant WHERE p.personID = participant.personID)
AND c.done = 0
ORDER BY courseExecutionID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it better, try to break your conditions in little pieces:

- SELECT courseExecution.courseExecutionID, courseExecution.beginDate,
  courseExecution.endDate, course.title, course.price, co.city WHERE:

  `SELECT c.courseExecutionID, c.beginDate, c.endDate, co.title, co.price, co.title`

---

- A person has not yet signed up for this execution, this gets checked
  in the participant table, if courseExecutionID is not linked to a
  participantID in the participant table then he has not signed up yet.

  `c.courseExecutionID NOT IN (SELECT courseExecutionID FROM participant)`

---

- The CourseExecution must not be done, pretty simple just check
  whether the done column is 0.

  `c.done = 0`

---

- availableDates.beginDate is smaller (<) than
  courseExecution.beginDate

  `a.beginDate < c.beginDate`

---

- availableDates.endDate is greater (>) than courseExecution.endDAte

  `a.endDate > c.endDate`

---

Adding your Joins, it should be like this:

```
SELECT c.courseExecutionID, c.beginDate, c.endDate, co.title, co.price, co.title
FROM courseExecution c
JOIN course co
ON c.courseID = co.courseID
JOIN availableDates a
ON co.courseID = a.courseID
WHERE c.courseExecutionID NOT IN (SELECT courseExecutionID FROM participant)
AND c.done = 0
AND a.beginDate < c.beginDate
AND a.endDate > c.endDate
```